# retrieving pyspark offset lag dynamic value in to other dataframe

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark, rdd

I am using pyspark 2.1. Below are my input dataframes . I am stuck up in taking dynamic offset values from different dataframe please help

df1=

category value

1 3

2 2

4 5

df2

category year month weeknumber lag_attribute runs

1 0 0 0 0 2

1 2019 1 1 1 0

1 2019 1 2 2 0

1 2019 1 3 3 0

1 2019 1 4 4 1

1 2019 1 5 5 2

1 2019 1 6 6 3

1 2019 1 7 7 4

1 2019 1 8 8 5

1 2019 1 9 9 6

2 0 0 0 9 0

2 2018 1 1 2 0

2 2018 1 2 3 2

2 2018 1 3 4 3

2 2018 1 3 5 4

As shown in above example df1 is my look up table which has offset values,for 1 offset value is 3 and for category 2 offset value is 2 .

in df2 ,runs is my output column so for every category values in df1 if the lag value is 3, then from dataframe2[df2] should consider the lag_attrbute and lag down by 3 values hence you could see for every 3 values of lag_attribute the runs were repeating

I tried below coding didn't work . Please help

```
df1=df1.registerTempTable("df1")
df2=df2.registerTempTable("df2")
sqlCtx.sql("select st.category,st.Year,st.Month,st.weekyear,st.lag_attribute,LAG(st.lag_attribute,df1.value, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY st.cagtegory ORDER BY st.Year,st.Month,st.weekyear) as return_test from df1 st,df2 lkp where df1.category=df2.category")
```

Please help me to cross this hurdle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lag` takes in a column object and an integer (python integer), as shown in the function's signature:

```py
Signature: psf.lag(col, count=1, default=None)
```

The value for `count` cannot be a pyspark `IntegerType` (column object). There are workarounds though, let's start with the sample data:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 3],[2, 2],[4, 5]], ["category", "value"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],[1, 2019, 1, 1, 1, 0],[1, 2019, 1, 2, 2, 0],[1, 2019, 1, 3, 3, 0],
                             [1, 2019, 1, 4, 4, 1],[1, 2019, 1, 5, 5, 2],[1, 2019, 1, 6, 6, 3],[1, 2019, 1, 7, 7, 4],
                             [1, 2019, 1, 8, 8, 5],[1, 2019, 1, 9, 9, 6],[2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0],[2, 2018, 1, 1, 2, 0],
                             [2, 2018, 1, 2, 3, 2],[2, 2018, 1, 3, 4, 3],[2, 2018, 1, 3, 5, 4]], 
                            ["category", "year", "month", "weeknumber", "lag_attribute", "runs"])
```

1. What you could do, if `df1` is **not too big** (meaning a small amount of `categories` and potentially a lot of values in each `category`), is convert `df1` to a list and create an if-elif-elif... condition based on its values:

   ```py
   list1 = df1.collect()
   sc.broadcast(list1)

   import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
   from pyspark.sql import Window
   w = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("year", "month", "weeknumber")
   cond = eval('psf' + ''.join(['.when(df2.category == ' + str(c) + ', psf.lag("lag_attribute", ' + str(l) + ', 0).over(w))' for c, l in list1]))
   ```

   **Note:** this is if `c` and `l` are integers, if they are strings then:

   ```py
   cond = eval('psf' + ''.join(['.when(df2.category == "' + str(c) + '", psf.lag("lag_attribute", "' + str(l) + '", 0).over(w))' for c, l in list1]))
   ```

   Now we can apply the condition:

   ```py
   df2.select("*", cond.alias("return_test")).show()

       +--------+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----------+
       |category|year|month|weeknumber|lag_attribute|runs|return_test|
       +--------+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----------+
       |       1|   0|    0|         0|            0|   2|          0|
       |       1|2019|    1|         1|            1|   0|          0|
       |       1|2019|    1|         2|            2|   0|          0|
       |       1|2019|    1|         3|            3|   0|          0|
       |       1|2019|    1|         4|            4|   1|          1|
       |       1|2019|    1|         5|            5|   2|          2|
       |       1|2019|    1|         6|            6|   3|          3|
       |       1|2019|    1|         7|            7|   4|          4|
       |       1|2019|    1|         8|            8|   5|          5|
       |       1|2019|    1|         9|            9|   6|          6|
       |       2|   0|    0|         0|            9|   0|          0|
       |       2|2018|    1|         1|            2|   0|          0|
       |       2|2018|    1|         2|            3|   2|          9|
       |       2|2018|    1|         3|            4|   3|          2|
       |       2|2018|    1|         3|            5|   4|          3|
       +--------+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----------+
   ```
2. If `df1` is **big** then you can self join `df2` on a built `lag` column:

   First we'll bring the `values` from `df1` to `df2` using a join:

   ```py
   df = df2.join(df1, "category")
   ```

   if `df1` is not too big, you should `broadcast` it:

   ```py
   import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
   df = df2.join(psf.broadcast(df1), "category")
   ```

   Now we'll enumerate the rows in each `partition` and build a `lag` column:

   ```py
   from pyspark.sql import Window
   w = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("year", "month", "weeknumber")
   left = df.withColumn('rn', psf.row_number().over(w))
   right = left.select((left.rn + left.value).alias("rn"), left.lag_attribute.alias("return_test"))

   left.join(right, ["category", "rn"], "left")\
       .na.fill(0)\
       .sort("category", "rn").show()

       +--------+---+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----+-----------+
       |category| rn|year|month|weeknumber|lag_attribute|runs|value|return_test|
       +--------+---+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----+-----------+
       |       1|  1|   0|    0|         0|            0|   2|    3|          0|
       |       1|  2|2019|    1|         1|            1|   0|    3|          0|
       |       1|  3|2019|    1|         2|            2|   0|    3|          0|
       |       1|  4|2019|    1|         3|            3|   0|    3|          0|
       |       1|  5|2019|    1|         4|            4|   1|    3|          1|
       |       1|  6|2019|    1|         5|            5|   2|    3|          2|
       |       1|  7|2019|    1|         6|            6|   3|    3|          3|
       |       1|  8|2019|    1|         7|            7|   4|    3|          4|
       |       1|  9|2019|    1|         8|            8|   5|    3|          5|
       |       1| 10|2019|    1|         9|            9|   6|    3|          6|
       |       2|  1|   0|    0|         0|            9|   0|    2|          0|
       |       2|  2|2018|    1|         1|            2|   0|    2|          0|
       |       2|  3|2018|    1|         2|            3|   2|    2|          9|
       |       2|  4|2018|    1|         3|            4|   3|    2|          2|
       |       2|  5|2018|    1|         3|            5|   4|    2|          3|
       +--------+---+----+-----+----------+-------------+----+-----+-----------+
   ```

**Note:** There is a problem with your `runs` lag value, for `catagory=2` it is only lagging `1` instead of `2` for instance. Also some lines have the same order (eg. the two last lines in your sample dataframe `df2` have the same `category, year, month and weeknumber`) in your dataframe, since there is shuffling involved you might get different results everytime you run the code.

Comment: Thanks alot MaFF. I am getting NameError "1" is not defined . In eval function the error with str(c) . Please help MaFF

Comment: Could you post the string contained in eval (without calling the eval function)

Comment: psf.when(df2.category == 1, psf.lag("lag_attribute", 3, 0).over(w)).when(df2.category == 2, psf.lag("lag_attribute", 2, 0).over(w)).when(df2.category == 4, psf.lag("lag_attribute", 5, 0).over(w)). Dear MaFF. I have mocked the data but in place of 2 , 4 there is string value . Hence it is throwing error as name error not defined. I am assuming when comparing with string it has to be df2.category=='abc123' . But I don't know how to convert str(c) to string value. MaFF. Tried different approach like giving str(c).cast("string") didn't work

Comment: Thanks a lot MaFF managed to change the data rather than the code MaFF